# Image content changed when Resized

Tags: jpeg

This is a coding question I believe as i'm sure some of the photo content is changed. I have seen some images before which basically changed to a different image when downloaded or resized.

I want to know how this is achieved, anyone got any idea?

Comment: Is this the trick you're talking about http://thume.ca/projects/2012/11/14/magic-png-files/

Comment: Thanks, any idea if it's possible to do this in Photoshop as I don't know how to use Ruby.

Comment: no sorry can' help you with Photoshop.